# What are the start shutdown.exe parameters?

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe, shutdown, parameters

I have created shortcuts that shut down my PC based on online tutorials. They always explain the how but not the why of the parameters included (e.g. [This tutorial](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000321.htm)). I wish to create a batch program (for fun, why else?) that shuts down my PC but I want to know what the parameters are for it. I know the parameters for the `shutdown` command, but what about `start shutdown.exe`? What parameters go with that? Aside from the `start` command's own parameters.

Comment: From the questions similar to this from across stack exchange, I have yet to find one that answers my question. So I created one.

Comment: you know from the CMD shell you can get all the options from " /?" after any command.  Did you want to create desktop buttons for different functions like sleep?  like shutdown - s -hybrid -t 0  .... means 0 timeout with quickstart option

Comment: @TonyStewart Unless I was wondering about different commands that go with shutdown.exe. Not shutdown command. However, according the best answer they work the same and have the same commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know the parameters for the shutdown command, but what about start
>   shutdown.exe? What parameters go with that?

Referencing your question above.  I don't believe there is a difference in parameters, the only thing start does is open the process in a separate command window instance.

So start shutdown.exe /s (/s meaning shutdown computer) is going to do the same thing as shutdown /s, the only difference is that a separate command prompt is going to open to initiate the command.

Here is a link to a reliable source for shutdown parameters.
https://ss64.com/nt/shutdown.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this command?

```
C:\> Shutdown /?
```

The /? switch will display help for the command.

Comment: I did that and therefore know what the commands are for it. I am not asking about that, but rather shutdown.exe

Comment: @AChildofGod `shutdown.exe` **is** the shutdown command.

Comment: @DavidPostill shutdown by itself (with other parameters) is the command, but using the start command to run shutdown.exe is what I am talking about. shutdown.exe is an application Windows has for shutdown and restarting, etc. It itself is not a command. I was wondering about the parameters associated with using shutdown.exe and the start command.

Comment: @AChildofGod <sigh> "`shutdown.exe` ... It itself is not a command". Yes it is. Any program is also a command.

Comment: @DavidPostill how is a program a command? The shutdown command initiates shutdown.exe.

Comment: @AChildofGod No it doesn't. Pressing the shutdown "button" does **not** run `shutdown.exe`" See [How does shutdown and boot work in Windows 7](http://forum.thewindowsclub.com/windows-tips-tutorials-articles/33170-how-does-shutdown-boot-work-windows-7-a.html)

Comment: @AChildofGod Running `shutdown` from a `cmd` shell is the same as running `shutdown.exe`

Comment: @DavidPostill is right about this and it would serve you well to heed him. First, shutdown.exe is a program, not a command, to be very precise. Commands are things like "dir" or "cls" which do not exist as discrete files but are programmed into the command interpreter "command.com". Typing shutdown into the command interpreter searches the known directories for an executable file called shutdown (shutdown.exe) and passes the entered arguments along to that file as it executes it. So typing "shutdown.exe" and "shutdown" are exactly the same. Start gives more control over how a program runs.